# Store intermediate results

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Say I have a hbase table with composite key- `Key1,Key2,Key3,Time`

I want to do use spark to do something like this:

```
Aggregate at -> Key1,Key2,Key3,DatePart(Time),Hour(Time) --->Save result in Another table (Step1Table)
```

Use above rdd to

```
Aggregate at -> Key1,Key2,DatePart(Time),Hour(Time) --->Save result in Another table (Step2Table)
```

Use above rdd to

```
Aggregate at -> Key1,DatePart(Time),Hour(Time) --->Save result in Another table (Step3Table)
```

The thing is when I want to save results to table, I dont want to do a simple insert, I want to do some sort of merge (if the record exist for the key), can someone please guide me

I think I need to create a overloaded TableOutputFormat, can someone please provide me an idea how can i handle it?

Answer (score 0):

HBase is a read/write media.  You can create new entries for the same rowkey: they will have a newer timestamp so they "effectively" replace the older one.

Therefore your Step1Table, Step2Table and Step3Table can be managed by :

- Read the aggregates for the given key from hbase.
- Add the new value to each of the aggregates: recompute the values
- Store the new values  back to the same key.

Essentially the work is not in special input/outpuformats (beyond using the TableInput/OutputFormat for HBase), but in your aggregate computation.